# Connection refused while running .net core 2.0 web api on docker

Tags: .net, ubuntu, docker

These are my beginnings with docker, however I'm stuck now.

When I run my .NET Core Web Api typing:

```
dotnet run
```

this is my result:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Users\...\PickCashOut.API\PickCashOut.Web
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

And everything works great. But after build docker container with this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk as builder
ENV DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT 1
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore PickCashOut.Web/PickCashOut.Web.csproj
RUN dotnet publish PickCashOut.Web/PickCashOut.Web.csproj -c Release -o out -r linux-x64

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/PickCashOut.Web/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PickCashOut.Web.dll"]
```

result is:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {25360c91-217e-4770-962a-6282970c245c} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

but I cannot access to endpoints any longer.

```
Failed to connect to 195.*.*.87 port 80: Connection refused
```

In general this build is for my ubuntu server, but I have tried it on windows the effect is the same.

Any special settings are required? I read many tutorials and I thought that this should work.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to try exposing the port in the container to the outside world. Add the following to your docker-compose file. This will map port 80 to the local host port 80

```
ports:
  -80:80
```

Comment: Added -p 80:80 to docker run instruction and worked. Thanks a lot!